# CMake External Project Symlinks

Tags: cmake

I am building an external project that generates shared objects with symlinks:

i.e.

```
libxml.so -> libxml.so.0.0.0
libxml.so.0 -> libxml.so.0.0.0
libxml.so.0.0.0
```

I want to copy these 3 files to my library output path. However, if I do:

```
ExternalProject_Add_Step(
    xml copy2lib
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_PATH}/xml/lib/ ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}
    DEPENDEES install
)
```

All of the symlinks are destroyed and there are essentially 3 copies of the library. I am aware of the following solution, i.e.:

```
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink ./libxml.so.0.0.0 ./libxml.so
WORKING_DIRECTORY ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}
```

However, in my case, the external project is generating dozens of libraries that follow this convention. Please tell me I don't have to manually repair every symlink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake has a poor support for file links (symlinks, hardlinks, etc.). Partially, this is because there is **no cross-platform view** of such thing: Windows and Linux have different interpretation of these terms.

So, when you want to operate with Linux symlinks in a specific way, use Linux-specific commands. Instead of cross-platform `cmake -E copy_directory` use Linux-specific `cp`:

```
COMMAND cp -Pr ${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_PATH}/xml/lib/ ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}
```

---

Note, that copiing symlink has a sence only for *relative* symlinks. If symlink contains *absolute* path, after copy it will refer to original library location, not to the copied one.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you!

For the record, I ended up using `COMMAND cp -a ${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_PATH}/xml/lib/. ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}`

Comment: Hard links are part of the upcoming CMake 3.19.